# ASP.NET OWIN Login with Microsoft Live ID - Invalid request and Google Redirect Url Mismatch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0, owin

I have a site published on Azure, the social auth work correctly on every device an pc, except for one user whom keeps receiving the error invalid request, every time he tries to login using Microsoft.

I was thinking that the reason were that he is blocking cookies, but I tried this and did not get the same error.

He tries to access my site from IE and Chrome, and still gets the same error on every social network. But for everyone else this works just fine.

Someone knows what could be the reason of this error?

Here it is some captures about the URL received and the error page on Windows Live and Google:

Google URL error: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://wtm.azurewebsites.net/signin-google&state=xuugnYO6064L0MSO643UyrcDcDvZm_sqndpnUUR_Bn3e3lQkmtFTCq1ZrfMluCbMZhoIEX9G8Vrp-RxNwFHUyxvx_4mpoJVJZnR-n0LFDJyPazQ0ujUsQ6Jl2EIStNS0_EsnZOIZtIJySlgFrIr_TzjNBoih1APWLnGaLBb6wPaLuXQktAeTHeeUBTTnN9HWXi2WtPCYx08wX0N87XJa1kkk-mMcp-ro5UD5oO1EIE4&client_id=950525637185-3f4qu6vhoemqps16mk88mrcf49tn7hvo.apps.googleusercontent.com&hl=es-419&from_login=1&as=-6673ad9c11de7b4d

[image: google redirect url mismatch]
Microsoft Live URL error: https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=5130#error=invalid_request&error_description=The%20provided%20value%20for%20the%20input%20parameter%20'redirect_uri'%20is%20not%20valid.%20The%20expected%20value%20is%20'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'%20or%20a%20URL%20which%20matches%20the%20redirect%20URI%20registered%20for%20this%20client%20application.&state=kZj77bUrMjKBFKTwBTVl_p7zkjcqWqBAe95pW-eQFanQaLWx9vHUpR5duFFcstJF4MKEUvBe_pymDNNc896dGPFDwNSP1-lQrsr0GYgtu2QtRJ6bdfQO4H0lCatbvW5yOs5DwD6_ItRL2irc6qitL03FkDEkiFUZYLAzhsUP6FjaEosTKGsnBXV0HljrRECl7RN2cuiuJWWJQJcxAUznC2Rj6zx76zkF-FNMHgFbvwM

[image: Microsoft Live ID Invalid Request]

Comment: Try comparing the URLs for this intermediary step on a successful login (i.e. right before you actually grant access to the application). In particular look at the `redirect_uri` portion of the querystring. I have no idea how it's even possible but your user seems to be passing the wrong one.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems both Google and Microsoft support multiple redirect URIs, so it may be as simple as just adding the one that the user having problems is getting sent to in addition to the main version, assuming your app is setup to respond to either version, which is fairly easy.

Comment: ok, thanks I am going to try this out.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I fixed the problem,he was using https instead of http, so I added the other redirect URL with http and this solved the problem.

Comment: BTW, you should use https exclusively for authentication, not http. And in fact, unless you don't care about session hijacking, you should probably run your entire site under https as soon as the user authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, he was using https instead of http, that were how the redirect URL were registered, I added this other URL redirection and now it works fine.

Thank you for your help!